# Do I add event listener in oncreate method or render method to an actor in libgdx?

Tags: android-studio, libgdx, event-listener, imagebutton

I want to add a click listener to my image button but I am unable to identify where to add that function.

Answer (score 2):

Between those two, definitely on `onCreate()`. It would not really make much sense to add the listener on `render()`, as you only need to add it once, rather than many times per second.

Here's an example of how you could add a listener to an ImageButton:

```
myImageButton.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
        // do stuff here
    }
});
```

You can read a bit more about listeners and Scene2D in general in the [official wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d).

Comment: how will I add my clicklistener here